# Akamai file upload from asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload video from asp.net application to Akamai server so that members of my application can view the video. I have an account on Akamai and have CP code. Now i want to upload video through c# code. If some one has idea then please guide me do this.

Thanks,

Munish

Answer (score 1):

Uploading to Akamai Edge Storage is done through FTP. Check Akamai documentation for how to get the details of the ftp account. Then go a web search for C# FTP libraries for how to push files to it.

Having said that, in almost all cases, you don't need to "upload" to Akamai at all. Whether you are delivery your video over http or streaming, Akamai can pick up the files straight from your web servers.

In Akamai terminology, this is known as setting up an "origin" server. As long as your server is on the internet, and the video files can be downloaded, then Akamai can use them. For full details, look in the Akamai documentation (either Http Content Delivery or Ondemand Streams) for using origin servers.